# HDInsight Emulator not running on Windows / connection exception

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to setup a HDInsight emulator on a Windows 8.1 PC following these instructions: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-emulator-get-started/

When trying to run a MapReduce job, I get a connection error.

How can I solve or further investigate this issue?

Details below.

**Prerequisites:**

- Installed Azure Powershell and Azure SDK for VS 2015
- Installed HDInsight Emulator for Azure incl. Hortonworks Data Platform
- Started local hdp services (13 services running)
- Connected Visual Studio to Emulator (had to follow troubleshooting point 2: replacing IP addresses in core-site.xml with '*' due to dynamic IP)
- Created directories and copied text files as suggested

**Problem:**

When trying to run the first example, I get the following error:

```
16/01/11 10:36:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1452503376359_0003 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1452503376359_0003 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1452503376359_0003_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000 due to: Call From EH3HOST/192.168.56.1 to EH3HOST:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
16/01/11 10:36:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

Search for XML files containing `<your own host name>:8020` inside the `c:\hdp\hdp-<Version Number>\etc\hadoop\` folder. (e.g. `EH3HOST:8020`)

You should find at least

- mapred-site.xml
- core-site.xml
- yarn-site.xml

Replace all occurrences within these files with `127.0.0.1:8020`.